# Problem in proving that the locus of all points S is a circle.

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry

> Given is a circle with midpoint $M$ and a chord $AB$ on this circle. $S$ is the intersection of the altitude from $M$ to $AB$. Prove that the locus of all points $S$ is a circle with midpoint $D$ and radius $|AD|$.

Set $\angle A=\alpha$.

$\left.\begin{array}{l}\angle ASM=\angle BSM=90^{\circ}  \\ |AM|=|BM| \text{ (circle)} \\ |MS|=|MS| \end{array}\right\}\implies \triangle ASM\cong\triangle BSM$ (RHS) $\implies \angle A=\angle B=\alpha$

$\left.\begin{array}{l} |AB|=2|AS| \\ \angle A=\angle A \\ |AM|=2|AD| \end{array}\right\}\implies \triangle ABM\sim \triangle ASD$ (SAS)

Now I know I have to prove that $DS\parallel MB$ and therefore $\angle B=\alpha=\angle ASD$. However, the proof in my book assumes this without proving. How would I go about completing the proof?

[image]

Comment: This might help you: [A line which bisects two sides of a triangle is parallel to the third.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105084/a-line-which-bisects-two-sides-of-a-triangle-is-parallel-to-the-third)

Answer (score 0):

$ASB$ is a right triangle, hence $DA=DS=DM$.
This gives that $S$ always belongs to the circle $\Gamma$ having $AB$ as a diamater: now you just have to prove the converse statement. If $S$ belongs to such a circle, $AS=SB$, since an homothethy with center $A$ and factor $2$ sends $\Gamma$ into the original circle.

Answer (score 0):

*ASM* is a right triangle,
*D* is the midpoint of *AM*,

Therefore *DA* = *DS* = *DM*.
And so *S* ∈ circle with radius |DA|.

Here is an animation to visualize the circle:
[image: the locus of midpoint of a chord]

But I don't know how to prove that *S* can be **everywhere** on the circle.
Maybe you can do that with *∠A* ? It seems to make a full turn when *A* or *B* moves.